# Weird bug with Trebuchet MS font

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the jquery.fullcalendar plugin using the jQuery UI theming.

Everything is ok, except that when the user try to select a time range (week or day view) the selection is displaced about one hour. You can see this behaivour in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/gQMvH/).

I've reduced the problem and I arrived to the conclusion that the problem comes from the CSS code. In the fiddle I've copied the problematic CSS code (corresponds to the jQuery UI CSS framework). If you remove this CSS code, the selection works fine (but without format, of course).

I've been trying to find which is the exact problem, but I cannot see.

**EDIT**: I've reduced the problem to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/gQMvH/1/). Now if you remove "Trebuchet MS" font from *.ui-widget* fullCalendar works!! See here [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/gQMvH/2/). The question now is, Why? I'm using Linux, I don't know if that has some effect...

Comment: Hmm... I seem to be getting an error in the fiddle example: outerLayout is not defined (line 644).  That seems to be causing the 'select a time range' functionality to fail (I'm guessing) because when I try to drag and drop a time range, nothing happens.

Comment: We've found the problem (please, read EDIT), but now I'm wondering why it's happening..

Comment: For what it's worth, your issue seems specific to Webkit and Opera. I can't reproduce it in IE or Firefox.

Comment: I can reproduce in Linux versions of Firefox and Chrome. I've not tried in Windows

Comment: font names of more than two words should be placed in "", and you may just need a linux backup, aka a better font stack for Trebuchet MS - http://www.codestyle.org/servlets/FontStack?stack=Trebuchet+MS,Tahoma,Arial&generic=sans-serif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove from your css the following:

```
.fc-agenda-slots td div {
    height:20px;
}
```

or change it to:

```
.fc-agenda-slots td div {
    height:auto;
}
```

I guess that the font size overflow the `div` of fixed `20px` with result to get this "weird bug".

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gQMvH/5/

Comment: Second option works (height:auto). It requires the !important modifier in my production system.

Answer (score 1):

I found the offending code.  It's

```
.ui-widget { font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
```

under `Component containers`.  Particularly the font-family declaration.  Removing it stops the odd behavior, but as to why it's causing it... no clue.

http://jsfiddle.net/5tAaj/

Comment: I've been faster :) But thanks!! Now the problem is why it's happening.. ARe you using Linux?

Comment: @Ivan Nope. I'm using Chrome 14 on Windows 7.  I'm not sure why that font would cause this problem.