# What is suppressing the CSS for a Wordpress plug-in?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed a menu plug-in to use with my WooCommerce Wordpress site. For some reason, my site isn't loading parts the plug-in's CSS files. In fact, when I temporarily disabled the whole CSS folder, the page appeared exactly the same.

There are fonts on that page aren't even part of my site's theme or custom CSS. Anyone know what could be causing this?

http://eatgoodathome.com/test-menu/

Comment: Can you point out where the font is different that it should be?

Comment: The headers, like "Beer-Can Chicken." It is a Times-esque font. The defaults for the site are sans serif, and I was specifying Playfair Display.

Comment: Turns out I figured it out by asking a different question, which was whether the fonts specified in the author's CSS was conflicting with something else. This solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827015/weird-bug-with-trebuchet-ms-font